# how to reverse selection with iCheck

Tags: javascript, html, icheck

I'm useing iCheck. Now i need to reverse selection when click on the reverse checkbox. I don't know how to do this. Has somebody done this before?

html

```
<input type="checkbox" id= "category_ids_select_reverse" name="category_ids_select_reverse">Reverse
<input type="checkbox" name="category_ids_select" value="">
```

js

```
var category_ids_select_reverse= $('#category_ids_select_reverse');
category_ids_select_reverse.on('ifChanged', function () {
    // how to reverse the selection?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `iCheck('toggle')`

```
$('#category_ids_select_reverse').on('ifClicked', function(){
        $('input[name="category_ids_select"]').iCheck('toggle');
});
```

Sample : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/binhminha0/5ev9ucxr)

Answer (score 1):

```
category_ids_select_reverse.on('ifChanged', function () {
    $('input[name="category_ids_select"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).iCheck('uncheck');
        } else {
            $(this).iCheck('check');
        }
    });
});
```

The code above work fine for me. FYI

Comment: What's `category_ids_select_reverse`?

Comment: sorry, there are some mistake in the code. I edited it again.